# Time Difference between 120 degrees phase shift signal or a 3 phase signsl

Tags: arduino

I am trying to create an Arduino 3 phase square wave code, and I wanted to know the time difference between each 120 degree phase shifts.

With some effort I could calculate it to be 6.66 millisecond.
Please let me know if I am missing something, or is the result correct?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Depends on your frequency.

Comment: It's for a 50 Hz frequency!

Comment: Then yes, it's 6.66.. ms delay between the phases.

Comment: OK, great! thanks so much for the help! Appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2):

The time difference between the three (120 degree shifted) square wave signals depends on the frequency of the signals that you are trying to make.

The period of a single signal is:
\begin{equation}
T=\frac{1}{F}
\end{equation}

The time between the signals is 1/3 of this period because they are 120 degrees shifted, giving the following equation:
\begin{equation}
T_{offset}=\frac{1}{3}T
\end{equation}

In your case (50 Hz frequency) the answer is 6,67 millisecond. Your result is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have a follow up question, kindly help me to figure this out...does this also mean that the ON/OFF time of each square wave pulse will be 6.67 ms in duration?

Comment: That depends on what you want. If you don't want the three signals to overlap then the ON time should be 6,67 ms and the OFF time should be 13,33 ms

Comment: yes, basically I am trying to replicate a 3 phase 50 Hz overlapping signal which I can use for triggering the inputs of 3 half bridge ICs IR2112..., the HIN, LIN inputs of the IC. So can I go ahead as per your above suggestion?

Comment: Can you use 100Hz and divide by 6 with a  2us deadtime  square ?

Comment: @SwagatamMajumdar Yes you could try the 6,67 ms and 13,33 ms times and see if it works. If necessary you could try making the signals a bit longer to compensate for the ton and toff times of your driver.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Could you be more specific in your question?

Comment: It was a suggestion to use an even number so that /2 results in a symmetrical half-wave

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Do you suggest using 100Hz? It makes sense since each IC has to go through two alternate hi/lo sequences?. Dead time may not be essential since the IC already has this feature internally. In that case what should be the recommended ON/OFF duration of each pulse?

Comment: @Leonvd, sure I will try that, just want to confirm whether 100Hz is the right frequency for switching the mentioned IC.

Comment: @Leonvd, Instead if I created a 50% duty using 6.66ms would that be technically incorrect? Because creating 50% duty cycle would be much easier in Arduino for me. I am not an expert with Arduino coding.

Comment: @SwagatamMajumdar I understand that making the duty 50% is easier to program but I do not think that it will work. To give a correct answer to your question I would need more information about your schematic and your intentions with it

Comment: @SwagatamMajumdar also, dont forget that if you want to try the duty of 50% that the ON and OFF times should both be 10 ms to keep the 50 Hz (or 5 ms if you want to try 100 Hz)

Comment: @Leonvd, thanks for pointing out that, yes each cycle should be 10ms ON, just as we have in  a normal single phase 50 Hz AC half wave cycle. This actually makes the problem much easier to implement now. Each cycle needs to be 10ms long and the partition between each cycle needs to be 6.66ms long. Please let me know if I am correct with my assumption.

Comment: No problems, this conversation has helped me to learn a lot regarding how to configure a 3 phase signal and I can now quite comfortably simulate it in my mind. I Thank all the contributors here who helped me to solve this problem! I am extremely grateful to all!!

Answer (score 1):

We can't give you a time as it depends on the frequency.

But given there are \$360^o\$ in a circle \$120^o\$ is one third of the period.

The most common mains frequencies are 50Hz and 60Hz.

For 50Hz as used in the UK and elsewhere

\$ \text{Period} = \dfrac{1}{50 \text{ Hz}} = 20 \text{ms} \$,  and \$ \text{Delay} = \dfrac{1}{3 \times 50 \text{ Hz}} \approx 6.667 \text{ ms} \$

For 60Hz as used in the US and elsewhere

\$ \text{Period} = \dfrac{1}{60 \text{ Hz}} \approx  16.666 \text{ms} \$,  and \$ \text{Delay} = \dfrac{1}{3 \times 60 \text{ Hz}} \approx 5.556 \text{ ms} \$

Answer (score 0):

```
50 Hz  ---...---...---...---...---...-- limited
100 Hz|  |  ^  |  ^  |  ^  |  ^  |   ^   XOR edge detect clock 0.1us
Phase A  _________|---------__________--- div /6

Phase B  ------_________|--------_________

Phase C  ______---------________|--------____
```

Using divide /3 counter to get 3 phases then /2 counter to get a square wave on each and ensure proper phase by initialization with a simple state machine design.

It is best to use 50 Hz hardware timer interrupts for stability.